# JavaFX - Style-class of HTMLEditor's toolbar buttons

Tags: button, javafx, toolbar, html-editor

Does anyone knows the names of the style-class for the HTMLEditor's toolbar buttons in image below ?

[image]

I got a list of the other buttons:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These CSS classes are in HTML-Editor > bottom-toolbar:

```
format-menu-button — ComboBox
font-family-menu-button — ComboBox
font-size-menu-button — ComboBox
```

See for details: [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#htmleditor)

Comment: If you can answer: do you know why I get NPE when I try to hide the combobox above ? For the other controls in ".bottom-toolbar" the following lines works perfectly: editor.lookup(".bottom-toolbar").lookup(".html-editor-underline").setVisible(false); editor.lookup(".bottom-toolbar").lookup(".html-editor-underline").setManaged(false);

Comment: The answers can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075841/how-to-hide-the-controls-of-htmleditor

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931588/options-for-html-editing-in-javafx

Comment: I had already tested most of the code, but no success. But thanks anyway....